# What happen if we remove checked exception from java?

Tags: java, exception

I have gone through this interview 
http://www.artima.com/intv/handcuffs.html
and some article and discussion about checked exception. That said `checked exception` is untried experiment to bring in java. It can bring versionability and scalability issues. Bruce eckel also provide a adapter to convert `checked exception` to `unchecked exception` to avoid called force to catch exception. I also heart hibernate move from `checked exception` to `unchecked exception`. I wonder what if we remove `checked exception` mechanism? I also agree that `checked exception` is not necessary existed.

Comment: Not sure what you're looking for in an answer-what if? We wouldn't have checked exceptions any more.

Comment: If java just dropped it tomorrow, nothing would break (assuming you left the syntax) but you'd probably have a lot of `catch(FooException e){throw new RuntimeException(e)}`'s left that would look a bit silly

Comment: The world will be a better place to live, prosper and write clear, unobtrusive code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not a lot would happen, actually. On the VM level, all exceptions are unchecked. You can verify this by doing e.g. the following:

```
public class A {
    public static void a() {
        /* Do nothing */
    }
}

public class B {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A.a();
    }
}
```

Store these classes in their respective files `A.java` and `B.java` and compile them. Then, change `A` to the following:

```
public class A {
    public static void a() throws Exception {
        throw(new Exception("foo"));
    }
}
```

Recompile `A.java` without recompiling `B.java`. Then run `B`, and you'll see the thrown exception from `A` propagating and terminating the program as if it were a `RuntimeException`, without the VM complaining of linkage errors or anything.

Checked exceptions are merely a syntax-level feature of the Java language. Removing it wouldn't affect the VM implementation or even the language model one bit.

Answer (score 1):

> I wonder what if we remove checked exception mechanism?

The short answer is that nothing would happen at the technical level<sup>1</sup>.

However there would be long and loud complaints from the significant body of Java programmers who believe that checked exceptions are actually a *good thing* ... or at least, they are better than the alternative of simply removing the distinction.

The people responsible for the creation evolution of the Java language over the past 15+ years have taken an essentially conservative approach, only making backwards compatible changes and only when there was broad acceptance that it was a good thing to do.  So, while dropping the checked / unchecked distinction is an "interesting" proposal, it is not likely to happen in Java (IMO).

---

<sup>1 - it is theoretically possible that there is code whose functionality *depends* on the compiler or something flagging mishandled checked exceptions as an error ... but I've never come across a situation where this would make sense.</sup>

Comment: Exactly so. I read in 1997 or so that when checked exceptions were introduced it triggered hundreds if not thousands of hitherto unknown bugs in the JDK.